# Nativescript "No Value for Main" Error, while using/require Casperjs

Tags: casperjs, nativescript

after installing casperjs in my application, while referencing the casperjs module,
var cas=require('casperjs');
Why do i get "No Value for Main"?
commenting out works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't casper.js reliant on a DOM being present? I don't think you can use this within Nativescript.

Comment: No, CasperJS relies on PhantomJS/Slimer.js, which probably cannot be run on Android an iOS.